# Magento2 : can i add search bar on top on layered navigation bar on category page

Tags: magento2, layout, search

[image]

how can i add search bar on left bar in category page.

Comment: Did you ever find the answer to this question? I'm also interested in this.

Comment: are you use layered navigation extension ?

Comment: you can call in .phtml file <?php 
                echo $block->getLayout()
               ->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')
               ->setBlockId('catalog-search')
               ->toHtml();
            ?>